# Multiply points of a string

Tags: javascript, string, typescript, numbers, points

Let's say that I have a list of points declared in this format: x1,y1 x2,y2

```
listOfPoints : string = "12.2, 13.0 198.2, 141";
```

What could I do to multiply by 1.5, for example, every number of this string ?
Do I need to iterate over the listOfPoints and extract a string every time that there is a ', ' or ' ', convert that string into a number, multiply it by 1.5 and reconvert it into a string to finally put it into a new string (newListOfPoints) ?

Or is there a different way to that more efficiently ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression with a replacer function to match digits, possibly with decimals, and replace with those digits multiplied by the number you want:

```js
const listOfPoints = "12.2, 13.0 198.2, 141";
const multiplied = listOfPoints.replace(
  /\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g,
  match => match * 1.5
);
console.log(multiplied);
```

Due to floating-point issues, some of the resulting numbers may have trailing digits. If you don't want that, you can round the multiplied number to a certain number of decimal places:

```js
const listOfPoints = "12.2, 13.0 198.2, 141";
const multiplied = listOfPoints.replace(
  /\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g,
  match => Math.round(1000 * match * 1.5) / 1000
);
console.log(multiplied);
```